# What is TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable?

Tags: python, arrays, new-operator

```
for j in range(640):
        for i in range(400):
            # nimg[j][i] = resam(img, x, y)
            K2 = K/2
            sum = 0.0
            a = -K2
            for s in range[a,K2+1, 1]:
                for t in range[a,K2+1, 1]:
                    sum += resam(img,x+(K2*d), y+(K2*d))
                    nimg[j][i] = int(sum/(K*K))
```

Error:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "PyIP2.py", line 56, in <module>
>     resize(img,nimg)
>   File "PyIP2.py", line 29, in resize
>     for s in range[a,K2, 1]:
> TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
> ```

*What is the solution for same as i am not able to understand?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mistake you did was to use [](square brackets) instead of ()(curve brackets)

The fix is simple:

```py
for j in range(640):
    for i in range(400):
        # nimg[j][i] = resam(img, x, y)
        K2 = K/2
        sum = 0.0
        a = -K2
        for s in range(a,K2+1, 1):
            for t in range(a,K2+1, 1):
                sum += resam(img,x+(K2*d), y+(K2*d))
                nimg[j][i] = int(sum/(K*K))
```

Comment: Now it's fixed. :)

Comment: TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PyIP2.py", line 56, in <module>
    resize(img,nimg)
  File "PyIP2.py", line 29, in resize
    for s in range(-K2,K2+1.0):

Comment: Replace 1.0 with 1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214794/discussion-between-harishankar-g-and-uday-posia).